# Iterative solutions of linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not understand that why $M$ must be invertible for $x^{(k+1)}$ to be uniquely specified in equation below:

$$ Mx^{(k+1)} = Nx^{(k)} + b \quad (k=0,1,\ldots).$$

Why $M$ must be invertible? And what means by $x^{(k+1)}$ to be uniquely specified ?

Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: What would happen, if $M=0$?

Comment: ... and, moreover, if $Nx+b=0$ has infinitely many (or no) solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}^n$ the linear system

$$Ax = b$$

has a unique solution $x$ if and only if $A$ is invertible.

In the iterative technique described above you want to generate successive approximations $x^{(n+1)}$ by solving a linear system. The system

$$\begin{align}M x^{(n+1)} &= Nx^{(n)} + b \\ &= \tilde{b}\end{align}$$

better have a (unique) solution! Therefore, $M$ must be invertible.